# how to install/use Google Client library on heroku

Tags: php, heroku, google-sheets, composer-php

Hello im trying to use my  the google sheets API v4 to get some sheet data on google sheet to a PHP that will be deployed in heroku, On google's [Quickstart Guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php#troubleshooting) step 2 it needs me to install the Google Client Library.

```
$ composer require google/apiclient:^2.0
```

But I do not know how to do this in heroku. I already have the two necesarry file the quickstart.php and credentials.json. That line even assumes composer is available on heroku.

Comment: What do you mean by "do this in heroku"? What have you tried so far, where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase i though wrong of what is a composer and basically most of the flow how a website is loaded, i though composer is some sort of an engine that runs the files. It seems to only compiles the all the dependencies needed into the project folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont install it on heroku. Composer is a program run on your computer that "composes" or gathers all the files and libraries necessary for the program to work. So really have to install PHP and Composer on your computer.